# windows forms application When I publish the applications and an end-user installs it on their PC it get stuck

Tags: c#, visual-studio, acrobat, publishing

windows forms application with an acrobat pdf viewer, When I publish the applications and an end-user installs it on their PC it gets stuck initializing the PDF the issue comes in on the publishing side maybe I don't have the right prerequisites checked, any help pls?

Comment: You didn't provide any information so it's impossible to help. What does `stuck` even mean? Missing dependencies lead to crashes, not frozen applications. Unless you added code that hides serious errors, making the application unresponsive instead of crashing.

Comment: Add proper logging to your application and check those logs. .NET contains a logging infrastructure through TraceListeners and sources going back to 2002. Newer libraries like Serilog make logging a lot easier. If you add an unhandled exception handler to the application, make sure it logs all info and notifies the user so they know what's going on.

Comment: How are you installing it? Have you created an .msi using WiX? Visual Studio setup projects? Is sounding like a missing dependency though. Check EventViewer might be something in there.

Comment: By default, application crashes are logged in Windows' Event Log. That's why hiding an unhandled exception is a bad idea - you lose any information about what happened and the application may end up in an unstable or frozen state. If the app crashes while loading the main form for example, hiding the error would result in a form that doesn't work

Comment: http://www.cloeteinnovations.com/gallery please follow this link and click on the medisinc button the application is not developed but select the button below, it will bring up a bunch of exercises when you click on them they just say initializing

Comment: Please ask end user to run Acrobat Viewer on the user PC before your application. Just to check that it is installed and does not show any dialog to the user on start. Acrobat Viewer asks to accept the license using the modal dialog box on first start. So, probably, you application `stuck` since viewer is waiting for user input somewhere in the dark background.

Comment: hi Ryan, I'm using Visual Studio setup project

Comment: thanks, Oleksa I'll try that